# a question about how to prove mutivariable integral, I am struggling about it!

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$, and then how to prove $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x_1) \, dx_1 \int_{a}^{x_1}f(x_2) \, dx_2 \cdots \int_{a}^{x_{n-1}}f(x_n) \, dx_n={1\over n!} \left[\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \right]^n$$

I really don't know how to solve it! I prefer to use mathematical induction,but it doesn't work. Can someone can help me to solve it? I will appreciate you very much.

Comment: Can you assume that $f(x)$ is also *continuous* on $[a,b]$? If yes, put $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$ and observe that since $F'(x) = f(x)$, for $n =2$ one has $$\int_a^b f(x_1)\left( \int_a^{x_1} f(x_2)\,dx_2 \right)dx_1 = \int_a^b F(x_1)f(x_1)\,dx_1 = F(x_1)^2\big|_a^b - \int_a^b F(x_1)f(x_1)\,dx_1.$$ Viewing the last equality as an equation for $\int_a^b F(x_1)f(x_1)\,dx_1$, we obtain $$\int_a^b F(x_1)f(x_1)\,dx_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(F(b)^2 - F(a)^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right]^2.$$

Comment: Assuming continuity of $f$, as in the above comment, observe that to make the induction step from $n-1$ to $n$, you may assume that you have proved the formula involving the $n-1$ times iterated integral for any function $f$ defined on *any closed interval* $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Thus, you may assume that for any $a \leq x_1 \leq b$, $$\int_a^{x_1} f(x_1)\,dx_1 \cdots \int_a^{x_{n-1}} f(x_n)\,dx_n = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left[\int_a^{x_1} f(x)\,dx\right]^{n-1}.$$ Then, we consider $$\int_a^b \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left[\int_a^{x_1} f(x)\,dx\right]^{n-1} f(x_1)\,dx_1.$$

Comment: (continued from last comment) The above integral equals $$\int_a^b \frac{F(x_1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}F'(x_1)\,dx_1 = \frac{F(b)^n}{n!} - \frac{F(a)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{n!}\left[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right]^n.$$

Comment: This is a pretty amazing formula, it deserves more than just a grudging proof.

Comment: For my tastes, the notation here does not sufficiently emphasize that this is an iterated integral, with some nested within others, rather than a product.  $\displaystyle\int_a^b\left( \int_a^{x_1}     \cdots dx_2 \right)\,dx_1$ might be overdoing it, but it's explicit about that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: My answer is a little sloppy in this regard too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tedious calculation:

Let $I=[a,b]$, and
Let $S = \{ x \in I^n \mid x_1 < \cdots < x_n \}$.

In the following, let $\sigma$ denote a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $S_\sigma = \{ x \in I^n \mid (x_{\sigma_1},\ldots,x_{\sigma_n}) \in S \}$, and note that the $S_\sigma$ are disjoint.

It is not hard to see that the function $x_n \mapsto 1_{S_\sigma}((x_1,\ldots,x_n))$ is Riemann integrable.

Let $\phi(x) = f(x_1)\cdot \cdot \cdot f(x_n)$ for $x \in I^n$, and note that  $\phi((x_{\sigma_1},\ldots,x_{\sigma_n})) = \phi(x)$.

Note that $\int_a^b \int_a^{x_1} \cdots \int_a^{x_{n-1}} \phi(x) \, dx_1 \cdots d x_n = \int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) 1_S(x)\,dx_1 \cdots d x_n $, and that
$\int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) 1_S(x)\,dx_1 \cdots d x_n = \int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) 1_{S_\sigma}(x)\,dx_1 \cdots d x_n $ for all permutations $\sigma$.

Hence $\int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) 1_S(x) \, dx_1 \cdots d x_n = {1 \over n!} \int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) \, dx_1 \cdots d x_n $.

Since $(\int_a^b f(t) \, dt )^n = \int_a^b \cdots \int_a^b \phi(x) \, dx_1 \cdots d x_n$, we see that
$\int_a^b \int_a^{x_1} \cdots \int_a^{x_{n-1}} \phi(x) \, dx_1 \cdots d x_n
= {1 \over n!}(\int_a^b f(t) \, dt )^n$.

**Note**: I haven't shown that the various integrals exist, however it is sufficient to note that if $g,h$ are Riemann integrable, then $g \cdot h$ is Riemann integrable. Furthermore, if $g$ is Riemann integrable, the function $t \mapsto \int_a^t g(x) dx$ is continuous, hence Riemann integrable.

**Note:** I have inadvertently used Fubini above. To justify this I need a
result which is that if $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ is integrable on $A\times B$, and $x \mapsto \int_B f(x,y)dy$, $y \mapsto \int_A f(x,y)dy$ are integrable on $A$, $B$ respectively, then the iterated integrals can be swapped. In addition, I would need to use the fact that any permutation can be written as the composition of a finite number of pairwise swaps. (This is only needed with the Riemann integral, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

With method of induction (beginning with a partial integration) :

[image]

Comment: I dont think differentiability is part of the assumption though.