# Prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}}dx=2^nn!$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}}dx=2^nn!$

My attempt:
On the region where  $x_1$ has the largest absolute value
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}}=2^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x_1|}dx=2^n\int_0^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}_r}e^{-|x_1|}dSdr$
But I got stuck here.

Comment: Where did $2^n$ come from? I ask this for learning, not for challenging your working. How does one get that from $\exp(-\max\{\cdots\})$?

Comment: For actual question helping, I believe that assuming $x_1$ has the largest absolute value is false, since saying that restricts you to a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ instead of the whole set

Comment: @FShrike $2^n$ probably comes from the symmetry of the integrand and the fact that there are $2^n$ "quadrants". For example if $n=2$, there are the four quadrants,  for $n=3$ there are the eight octants and so on. The integral over each piece is equal due to the symmetry of the integrand under change of $x_i\mapsto -x_i$. So, if we let $A_{+}=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n\,:\, x_1\geq0,\dots x_n\geq 0\}$, then we have to show the integral over $A_+$ is $n!$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you @peek-a-boo. This now reminds me of a Gaussian integral

Comment: @peek-a-boo I do not understand something. In the integrand there is no variable x, over which the integration is performed. There are only x1, x2..xn.

Comment: @ReneMorningstar $dx$ here means integration with respect to the $n$ variables $dx_1\dots dx_n$. This is an integral in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and $dx$ is just a short way of writing it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo 1) Due to the symmetry of the variables, all R^n is divided into n equal sectors, where x_k is maximal modulo, k=1,...n. (the rest has measure zero and does not count). 2) For a specific sector, we reduce the integral to a repeated one. 2) The integral over all variables, except max, will be equal to the volume of the cube with the edge 2|x_max|, that is, (2x_max)^(n-1).

Comment: 3) We get int(e^(- |x_max|)*(2 |x_max|)^(n-1))dx_max=2*2^(n-1)*G (n)=2^(n)*(n-1)! (here the two is taken since our integral is from-oo to +oo, and Gamma is from 0 to +oo). 4) Well, it remains to multiply by n, by the number of sectors. Do you think my approach is reasonable?

Comment: Maybe related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815662/a-question-about-how-to-prove-mutivariable-integral-i-am-struggling-about-it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are $n$ cases, all of them mutually exclusive (except on a set of measure $0$):
$$E_k=\{|x_k|=\max\{|x_j|:1\leq j\leq n\}, \quad k=1,\ldots,n$$

One each $E_k$, by Fubini's theorem yields
$$\int_{E_k}e^{-\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|x_j|}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-|x|}\Big(\int^{|x|}_{-|x|}\,dx_2\ldots\int^{|x|}_{-|x|}\,dx_n\Big)\,dx$$

Thus, thee integral of interest becomes
$$n\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-|x|}2^{n-1}|x|^{n-1}\,dx=n2^n\int
^\infty_0x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx=n2^n\Gamma(n)=2^n n!$$

---

For another more geometric [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740846/121671), similar to polar coordinates, notice that $\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|x_j|=\|x\|_\infty$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It is not difficult to check (via monotone class arguments) that for any norm $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and any nonnegative measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\rho(x))\,dx=n \lambda_n(\{x:\rho(x)\leq1\})\int^\infty_0 f(r) r^{n-1}\,dr$$
where $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For the particular norm $\|\,\|_\infty$, the *volume* of the $\|\;\|_\infty$-unit ball is $2^n$

Comment: Well done @Oliver Diaz :)

Comment: I've figured where I was wrong thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

I have another nice approach (hope you'll agree on that):

From symmetry on the sign:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{-\max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}}=
2^n\int_{\mathbb{R_{+}}^{n}}e^{-\max\{x_1,...,x_n\}}$$

By taking a permutation $0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$, and taking the limit of the growing set $\lim_{k\to\infty}E_k = [0,k]^n$ we get

$$2^n\cdot n! \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R_{+}}^{n}\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|0\leq x_1\leq...\leq x_n\}}e^{-\max\{x_1,...,x_n\}} \\= 
2^nn!\int_{\{0\leq x_1\leq...\leq x_n\}}e^{-x_n} \\=
2^nn!\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^k \int_{x_1}^k...\int_{x_{n-1}}^k
e^{-x_n}$$

Im going to put $k=\infty$ just to make everything shorter. we get:

$$2^n\cdot n!\int_0^\infty \int_{x_1}^\infty...\int_{x_{n-1}}^\infty
e^{-x_n} = 2^n\cdot n! \int_0^\infty e^{-x_1} = 2^nn! $$