# How to integrate the maximum norm on $R^n$?

Tags: integration

> Let $|x|$ be the maximum norm such that $|x| = \max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Calculate the following integral:
> $$ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \max(0,1-|x|)\ dx.$$

I don't know how to calculate this integral. Maybe I should try to fix

$$x_{ n }\in\left[ -1,1 \right]?$$

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: First of all, $\lvert \cdot\rvert$ here is supposed to define a norm, not a metric (although of course the norm naturally induces a metric, but they are still different objects). Secondly, it should be $\lvert x\rvert=\max(\lvert x_1\rvert,\dots,\lvert x_n\rvert)$ (notice the absolute values).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Im not the best latex editor..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\}}dx=2^nn!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219624/prove-int-mathbbrne-max-x-1-ldots-x-n-dx-2nn) It is not an exact duplicate, but the technique will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint:

Denote $\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty:=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_j|$, where $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\intercal$.

1. Consider the sets $E_k=\{\mathbf{x}: \|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty\leq 1, \, |x|_k=\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty\}$. Notice that this are pairwise disjoint almost surely, that is $m(E_k\cap E_j)=0$ whenever $j\neq k$ where $m$ I Lebesgue's measure.
2. By symmetry,  the integral of interest can be rewritten as
   $$\int_{\{\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty\leq1\}}(1-\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty)\,d\mathbf{x}=\sum^n_{j=1}\int_{E_j}(1-|x_j|)\,d\mathbf{x}=n\int_{E_1}(1-|x_1|)\,d\mathbf{x}$$
3. Calculate
   $$\int_{E_1}(1-|x|_1)\,d\mathbf{x}=\int^{1}_{-1}(1-|x_1|)2^{n-1}|x_1|^{n-1}\,dx_1$$

Comment: I really thank you, i will try to solve it now. :)

Comment: I hope you can fill in the gaps I left and that you learn a few things along the lines. The main thing, besides this business of integrating over disjoint regions is Fubini's theorem. Also, perhaps you can also upvote my answer.